# Adding strings to stringArray android

Tags: android, string

i've problem when adding  string to a stringArray. It crashes every time:

```
ArrayList<String> newString, limits;

    String pruebas;     
    pruebas=e1.getText().toString();
    if (pruebas == null || pruebas.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Limits.this, "You did not enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else{
        limits.add(pruebas);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thankyou

Comment: Is this string-array or Arraylist<String>?

Comment: And please post logcat output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Use below code, it will solve your problem.

**Code for Add String into ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<String> limits = new ArrayList<String>();

String pruebas=e1.getText().toString();

if (pruebas == null || pruebas.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(Limits.this, "You did not enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}else {
    limits.add(pruebas);
}
```

**Code for Add String into String Array**, Here 10 is size of String Array and index is position of string array which you want to store the string value.

```
String[] limits = new String[10];

String pruebas=e1.getText().toString();

if (pruebas == null || pruebas.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(Limits.this, "You did not enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}else {
    limits[index] = pruebas;
}
```

Comment: How do you view an indexed `limits`? For example, `limits[0]`. I tried that it gives me: `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 2):

You have not intialize ArrayList... so  use this below

```
   ArrayList<String> newString, limits;

   limits = new ArrayList<String>();

   newString = new ArrayList<String>();

    String pruebas;     
    pruebas=e1.getText().toString();
    if (pruebas == null || pruebas.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(Limits.this, "You did not enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    else{
        limits.add(pruebas);
    }
```